# Jest: how to create a __tests__ folder which mirrors the src directory?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

Using Jest (for React testing) I would like to have my tests in their own directory, mirroring the src dir. Ex:

```
appRoot
├── src
│   └── components
├── __tests__
│   └── components
```

I do **not** want to have my tests inside the src folder

Answer (score 0):

The default config of at least Jest 26.6 uses these globs:

```js
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
```

`__tests__/` can be anywhere in your project directory, including the top level alongside `src/`. It does not have to be *in* your `src/` directory.